# How to ignore all files beside specific ones (which not to ignore)

Tags: git

We often use `.gitignore` to ignore files or folders.

> How can I do the reverse things?

I just want to add specific files &r folders I interest in.

Comment: What do you mean with focused?

Comment: Do you want everything to be ignored except some focused files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

#### Option 1:

- Use the `!` sign to "not ignore" the required patterns

  ```
  ### This is your git ignore file:

  # ignore all files and folders
  **/**

  # Add any specific required files
  !<file/path>
  ```

#### Option 2:

- ignore all your files ad use the `git add -f` (force flag) to add any required tracked files

  ```
  ### This is your git ignore file:

  # ignore all files and folders
  **/**
  ```

  To add the desired files
     `git add -f <file/path>`